# A fast algorithm for a probabilistic counting problem without replacement?

Tags: pr.probability, algorithms

Consider the integers $\{1,\dots, N\}$ for some positive integer $N$.  Let us suppose that for each $\{1, \dots, N\}$ there is an associated probability $p_1, \dots, p_N$. We also define an integer threshold  $1 \leq n < N$.

We sample independently and repeatedly **without** replacement from  $\{1,\dots, N\}$. For each $i \in \{1,\dots, N\} $ we sample the integer $i$ with probability $p_i$.  As we are sampling without replacement these probabilities will have to be appropriately scaled after each new integer is sampled.

> Is there a fast algorithm to compute the expected number of distinct
> integers less than or equal to the threshold $n$ in a sample of size
> $x$?

The expected value we want to compute [is](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4096918/678546) $\sum_{i=1}^n q_i$ where
$$q_i = \sum_{y = 1}^x \sum_{\substack{\{j_k \neq i\text{ distinct}\}\\k=1,\dots,y-1}}\left(\prod_{k=1}^{y-1}\frac{p_{j_k}}{1 - \left(\sum_{\ell = 1}^{k-1} p_{j_{\ell}}\right)}\right)\frac{p_i}{1 - \left(\sum_{\ell = 1}^{y-1} p_{j_{\ell}}\right)}.$$

However, this is infeasible to compute for anything but the smallest problem instances.

> Is there an efficient algorithm for this problem?

Comment: Do you mean probability *proportional* to $p_i$ rather than equal to $p_i$? Even if initially we have $\sum_i p_i=1$ after the first sampling the sum of the remaining $p_i$ will not be 1 anymore.

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev Yes.  After every integer is sampled the probability of the remaining integers will of course have to be scaled to make them add to one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you ask for "distinct integers" when sampling without replacement guarantees distinctness.

Let $q_i=1-p_i$.  The ordinary generating function
$$F(u,y) = \prod_{i=1}^n (q_i+p_i uy) \prod_{i=n+1}^N (q_i+p_iy)$$
counts subsets with $u$ monitoring the choices in $[1..n]$ and
$y$ monitoring all choices.

To extract the expectation of the number of choices in $[1..n]$, differentiate with respect to $u$.
If your sample size is $k$ (sorry but I can't use $x$ for an integer parameter when playing with generating functions), extract the coefficient of $y^k$.

So $$\text{answer} = \frac{[y^k] F_u(1,y)}{[y^k] F(1,y)},$$
where $[y^k]$ means extract the coefficient of $y^k$.

Now to computation.  Start with the denominator
$$F(1,y) = \prod_{i=1}^N (q_i+p_i y).$$
I don't know of any super-clever way to extract the
coefficient of $y^k$ but you can just start with the
polynomial $1$ and multiply by one factor at a time
discarding any powers greater than $k$. That will
have complexity $O(kN)$.
Probably there are options with lower theoretical
complexity but the constant here is so small that it
will be hard to beat for practical sizes.

The numerator is
$$F_u(1,y) = \sum_{i=1}^n p_i y\prod_{j\ne i} (q_j+p_jy),$$
which you can compute in similar manner.

ADDED. I'll explain how to get a good estimate for large problems, assuming that $k$ is not very small. I'll consider only the denominator. The function $F(1,y)$ is the pgf of the sum of $N$ independent Bernoulli random variables. The sum satisfies a local central limit theorem (LCLT) but that won't help immediately unless $k$ is close to the mean of the sum. Now introduce a parameter $\alpha\gt 0$ and replace $q_i+p_iy$ by $(q_i + \alpha p_iy)/(q_i+\alpha p_i)$ for each $i$. Solve for $\alpha$:
$$ \sum_{i=1}^N \frac{\alpha p_i}{q_i+\alpha p_i}=k,$$
which should be fairly easy numerically as there is no cancellation and the left side is monotonically increasing in $\alpha$.

With this value of $\alpha$, the mean of the sum of the tilted Bernoulli random variables with pgf $(q_i + \alpha p_iy)/(q_i+\alpha p_i)$ is exactly $k$. Now you can apply a LCLT such as Theorem 6.3 in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.05820) to get quite a good estimate.

If you want an arbitrarily accurate value, you can apply a fourier inversion theorem to the characteristic function and evaluate it numerically to the precision you desire. I don't know if this will be easy, but for sure it will be advantageous to tilt the distribution first as I did above.

Comment: _I'm not sure why you ask for "distinct integers" ..._ That surely comes from a previous (and equivalent) problem statement, where one samples with replacements (leaving the probabilities unchanged) and stops after getting $n$ different values. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4096509/expected-number-of-distinct-integers-found-with-variable-stopping-time

Comment: Yes probably, but "without replacement" and "distinct" are the same, which could have indicated a mistake in the description.

Comment: @leonbloy Yes it was exactly that.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay thank you for this answer.  I would be very interested in any methods with lower theoretical complexity. In particular that might be feasible when $N \approx 10^8$ and $k \approx 10^5$.

Comment: Thank you again.